# C argument doesn't match prototype

Tags: c

I'm trying to read from a file and insert it into my struct compound variable of 'codon' but I'm getting an error of 'arguments doesn't match prototype'.

Here is my .c:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "genome.h"

void LoadGeneticCode(filename, c){
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

}
int main()
{
    codon c[64]; //making array of c
    LoadGeneticCode('data.dat', c);
    return 0;
}
```

.h

```
typedef struct { char b1,b2,b3; int a;} codon;

void LoadGeneticCode(char *filename, codon c[64]);
```

makefile

```
HEADERS = genome.h

default: genome

genome.o: genome.c $(HEADERS)
    gcc -c genome.c -o genome.o

genome: genome.o
    gcc  genome.o -o genome

clean:
    -rm -f genome.o
    -rm -f genome
```

I feel like it's a simple type miss match but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: In ANSI C you'd normally include the `char *filename, codon c[64]` type specification in your function definition in your .c file too, rather than just the names. That might be it, I'm not sure what the behaviour is defined to be as you've done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First bad point: `void LoadGeneticCode(filename, c){`
You should specify types of each arguments. They are treated as `int` arguments and so it won't match the prototype.

Second bad point: `LoadGeneticCode('data.dat', c);`

Putting multiple characters in character constant `'data.dat'` isn't good. It should be a string `"data.dat"`.

You should write your .c like this:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "genome.h"

void LoadGeneticCode(char *filename, codon c[64]){
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

}
int main(void)
{
    codon c[64]; //making array of c
    LoadGeneticCode("data.dat", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's better to use `char const* filename`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `.c` file, try changing

```
void LoadGeneticCode(filename, c){
```

to

```
void LoadGeneticCode(char *filename, codon c[64]){
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function call in `main` -

```
LoadGeneticCode('data.dat', c);       // string literals should be in double quotes
```

Instead try this-

```
LoadGeneticCode("data.dat", c);
```