# C Load data from file into struct compiles but crashes during runtime

Tags: c, struct

I am currently trying to load a file into a struct consisting of 3 characters and 1 integer. The program should read from a data file and insert each line into an element of the struct. The first 3 properties being the first 3 characters of the line, then skipping the space and inserting the next characters(regardless of length) as an integer.

I was able to compile the program but it will not run. After some testing, I noticed that the program will not run with just the fscanf(). I'm not sure where to put the .dat file so I put it in the same folder as the exe.

An example of the data:

```
ABC 22
CDD 32
```

Here is my .c file:

```
void LoadGeneticCode(char *filename, codon c[]){
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    int i = 0;

    while(fscanf(file, " %c%c%c %d", &c[i].b1,&c[i].b2,&c[i].b3,&c[i].a) > 0){
            printf("%s \n",c[i].b1);
            i++;
     }
    fclose(file);
}
```

.h file:

```
typedef struct { char b1,b2,b3; int a;} codon;

void LoadGeneticCode(char *filename, codon c[64]);
```

Comment: You are using the `%1s` string format specifier in `scanf` but your target variable is `char`. It should be `%c` but depending how you enter the data, perhaps ` %c` with a space.

Comment: A similar question also using `codon c[64]` was asked earlier today. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761443/c-argument-doesnt-match-prototype/33761537#33761537 funnily enough by the same OP.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes that was addressing a different issue. I'm unfamiliar with c and have been trying to do it just based off of examples and google so when I run into an issue, even a simple one will take me a long time to debug.

Comment: you should pass a third parameter with the max number of entries in the array of `codon` structs so the function can/will stop if that array gets full

Comment: when calling the `fopen()` function, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.   when calling the `fscanf()` function, always check the returned value, as the code is doing, but use the number of format specifiers, NOT just `>0` because fscanf() returns the number of successful input/conversion operations.  In this case, the returned value must be 4 otherwise some error occurred

Comment: regarding this line: `while(fscanf(file, " %c%c%c %d", &c[i].b1,&c[i].b2,&c[i].b3,&c[i].a) > 0)`,  it should also be checking for the codon array being full, before reading more data, so, if the new input parameter is called maxCount,  then the line should be: `while( (i<maxCount) && (fscanf(file, " %c%c%c %d", &c[i].b1, &c[i].b2, &c[i].b3, &c[i].a) == 4) )

Comment: in general, it is a bad idea to call a variable name the same as a type name, even if the capitalization is different, as such code leads to confusion.  A better name (and quite commonly used) for the file pointer returned from the call to fopen() would be `fp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%1s` means one character, yes, but it also null-terminates the string. You're overwriting memory outside your intended buffer. `%c` is what you mean. You also don't need the temporary character variables, you can read directly into your structure fields.

Also `scanf` returns the number of fields successfully read, so your check has to be that it's >0 (or just equal to 4), not equal to 1.

Comment: the `>0` is not good enough as a failure to input/convert all 4 variables would pass but the result would be wrong.   Suggest only use `==<number of input/convert specifiers`  in this case `== 4`